# Тестирование контроллера на основе openApi средствами osteel/openapi-httpfoundation-testing?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, swagger, openapi

Требуется на основе документации из yaml проверить ответ контроллера средствами osteel/openapi-httpfoundation-testing.
Загвоздка в том, что если в ответ добавить не описанные в документации поля, тест проходит.
Что можно в документации указать, чтобы нельзя было принимать лишние поля. Возможно есть решение и со стороны инструмента osteel/openapi-httpfoundation-testing. Буду рад любой подсказке

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось совершил тупейшую ошибку: не обновил файл из источника.

Решение: добавить поле `additionalProperties: false` для нужного объекта